# Animate View and keep visible after animation

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I have two indicators, each need to be invisible to start. I want them to be visible after animating in, how do i do this? Right now they animate in then disappear, here is the code:

```
                indicator.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                indicator2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Animation fadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.fade_in_view);

                indicator.startAnimation(fadeInAnimation);
                indicator2.startAnimation(fadeInAnimation);
```

My xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:duration="1500"
        android:repeatCount="0" />
</set>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this: `fadeInAnimation.setFillAfter(true)`

or

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:duration="1500"
        android:repeatCount="0"
        android:fillAfter="true"/>
</set>
```